# Получение attr у form

Tags: jquery, атрибуты, form

Приветствую! столкнулся с непонятным.

случай первый:

```
<form id='form'>
</form>
<a id='link'>link</a>
```

второй:

```
<div id='form'>
</div>
<a id='link'>link</a>
```

обработка

```
$("#link").on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).prev().attr("id"));
});
```

вопрос - почему не работает в первом случае и работает во втором. Как заставить работать первый вариант?

Comment: Всё работает: http://jsfiddle.net/T8Ze8/

А вот использовать несколько элементов одинаковым id - нельзя.

Comment: спасибо, ид совместно не используются, это пример. Еще раз спасибо за подсказу, оно в самом деле не работало, причину нашел 

в том, что у form был родитель table

<table>
        <form id='form'>
        </form>
                <a id='link'>link</a>

</table>

пример тут http://jsfiddle.net/ZdUPw/